# In My Laravel Passport Application, how can I accept access_tokens (when the client does not send a Bearer header)

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I am using an OAuth2 client that does not send Authorization: Bearer but the standard laravel/passport setup checks this header. How to make it compatible from Laravel side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following middle ware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


class ConvertTokenToBearer
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param                          $next
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        if ($request->get('access_token')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->get('access_token'));
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And add it to your  app/Http/Kernel.php file.

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\ConvertTokenToBearer::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```